# Why doesn't javascript function update DOM on first run

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, dynamic

I have a dynamic form in which users can add inputs by clicking a button.  This works fine.  However when clicking to remove the input the first click does not remove an input.  Every click after removes inputs as expected.  I can see that it runs the function on first click to remove but nothing is updated in the DOM so the field stays.  Here is my HTML:

```
<button onclick="AddFileField()">Add File</button>
<br />
<br />
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div id="fileFields"></div>
    <br />
    <input type="submit" value="Upload" />
</form>
```

And the associated javascript:

```
function removeField() {
    $('.removeclass').click(function () {
        $(this).parent().remove();
    });
    return false;
}

var FieldCount = 1; //to keep track of text box added
function AddFileField() {
    var MaxInputs = 10; //maximum input boxes allowed
    var InputsWrapper = $("#fileFields"); //Input boxes wrapper ID
    var x = $("#fileFields > div").length + 1; //current text box count

    if (x <= MaxInputs) //max input box allowed
    {
        $(InputsWrapper).append('<div class="fileInp"><label for="file' + FieldCount + '">File:</label><input type="file" name="files" class="inpinl" id="file' + FieldCount + '" /><a href="#" class="removeclass" onclick="removeField()">&times;</a></div>');
        FieldCount++;
    }
    return false;
}
```

A [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3e1ajtvo/8/) showing issue.  To duplicate add a couple fields then click an x.  The first click does nothing, then proceeding clicks removes fields.  How can I get the first click to remove the field as well?

Comment: First time you click on x click handler is attached, second time - it executes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because you are registering your event handler inside of another event handler.

http://jsfiddle.net/3e1ajtvo/11/

I removed your event handler and now, you pass the clicked element as `elem` into the function itself.

As a matter of fact you don't even really need the function, as long as jquery is exposed (it is in your case).

http://jsfiddle.net/3e1ajtvo/12/

Answer (score 1):

A working fiddle is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/3e1ajtvo/10/)

The issue lies in the function:

```
function removeField() {
    $('.removeclass').click(function () {
        $(this).parent().remove();
    });
    return false;
}
```

When you click the `X`, this function is called, which adds a `click` event handler to the `X` to remove it; however, this event handler is not called until the next time you click it. (This is why clicking `X` twice works).

In the updated fiddle, you simply pass `this` to removeField as such:

```
//HTML
<a href="#" class="removeclass" onclick="removeField(this)">&times;</a></div>

//JS
function removeField(me) {
    $(me).parent().remove();
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason for this is because you are using `onclick="removeField()"`.

Lets take a look at your function. When you click on the remove button the following script will run. This script then ***creates*** a click handler, that will activate on *next* click, because when you first clicked on remove the handler was not created

```
function removeField() {
    $('.removeclass').click(function () {
        $(this).parent().remove();
    });
    return false;
}
```

So you will need to replace this is another function. Since you are using jQuery you can learn to use [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) for dynamically generated elements.

```
$(document).on('click', '.removeclass', function () {
    $(this).parent().remove();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Spokey/3e1ajtvo/16/

Comment: Thanks for the alternative.  I load jQuery and my external javascript file in the body so I get an error saying $ undefined, because I think jquery has not finished loading yet.  It runs find after clicking through that debug error.  Any solution to this aside from moving the jquery load up into head, which seemed to prevent the error?

Answer (score 1):

I made your code a bit more modular and changed it to use jQuery more than you were. This is just another way to do it, the other answers are also valid.

http://jsfiddle.net/3e1ajtvo/19/

```
var fields = {
    btnAdd: $('#addField'),
    inputWrapper: $('#fileFields'),
    maxInputs: 10,
    fieldCount: 1,    
    init: function(){
        this.inputWrapper.on('click', '.removeclass', this.removeInput);
        this.btnAdd.on('click', this.appendField);
    },
    removeInput: function(){
        //this will refer to the html element you clicked on
        $(this).parent().remove();
    },
    appendField: function(){
        //this will refer to the html element you clicked on
        if ( fields.inputWrapper.children('div').length <= fields.maxInputs ){
            fields.inputWrapper.append('<div class="fileInp"><label for="file' + fields.fieldCount + '">File:</label><input type="file" name="files" class="inpinl" id="file' + fields.fieldCount + '" /><a href="#" class="removeclass">&times;</a></div>');
            fields.fieldCount++;
        }
    }

};

fields.init();
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not executing the code to remove the row on the first click, you're just adding the click handler to the link. It works after that because the $('.removeclass').click(... then fires as expected.